# Java Applet MouseListener not working

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent

I thought I programmed it so that when I click on the 'Start' button that appears when it is not level 1 or higher, it would go to level 1. But nothing happens when I click it.

`import java.applet.Applet;`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Font;

public class Move extends Applet implements KeyListener, MouseListener {
private Rectangle rect;
private ArrayList<Integer> keysDown;
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int speed = 4;
int level = 0;
int xpos; 
int ypos; 
boolean startClicked; 
Image block;
Image start;
URL base;
MediaTracker mt; 
int randomx = randomGenerator.nextInt(560);
int randomy = randomGenerator.nextInt(360);


public void init() {
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50);      ///////////////////////////////////you can use rect.getX();
    mt = new MediaTracker(this); 
    try {
        base = getDocumentBase(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {} 
    block = getImage(base, "block.gif");
    start = getImage(base, "start_button.png");
    mt.addImage(block, 1);
    try { 
        mt.waitForAll(); 
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException  e) {} 
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setSize(600, 400);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    if (level != 0) {
        g2.fill(rect);
        //g.drawImage(block, randomx, randomy, this);      ###############################fhjvhfjvkjerhgvgf
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18);
        g.setFont(font);
        String text = "Speed: " + speed;
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        int x = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text)) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) + fm.getAscent();
        g.drawString(text, x, y);
    }
    else { // start menu
        g.drawImage(start, 160, 160, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode()))
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
moveRect();
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}

public void moveRect() {
    if (level != 0) {
        int x = rect.x;
        int y = rect.y;
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
            y -= speed;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
            y += speed;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
            x -= speed;
        }
        if (keysDown.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
            x += speed;
        }
        rect.setLocation(x, y);
        repaint();
        if (x-32 > randomx-72 && y+64 > randomy && x-32 < randomx+72 && y-64 < randomy) { /// will be flag
            randomx = randomGenerator.nextInt(560);
            randomy = randomGenerator.nextInt(360);
            speed += 4;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    if (level == 0) {
        xpos = me.getX(); 
        ypos = me.getY();
        if (xpos > 160 && ypos > 96 && xpos < 400 && ypos < 160) {
            level = 1;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
}
}
```

Thanks again for all the help! This will HOPEFULLY turn out to be a maze game...

PS: ignore the pointless comments.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing at

```
g.drawImage(start, 160, 160, this);
```

But checking for

```
        if (xpos > 160 && ypos > 96 && xpos < 400 && ypos < 160) {
```

Change that to

```
        if (xpos >= 160 && ypos > 159 && xpos < 400 && ypos < 190) {
```

Better yet make constants of these numbers or use an ImageIcon and add a listener to it.

```
   public static final int START_X_POS = 160;
   public static final int START_Y_POS = 160;

   public static final int START_WIDTH = 30;
   public static final int START_HEIGHT = 150;
```

//...

```
        if (xpos >= (START_X_POS ) && ypos >= START_Y_POS  && xpos <= ( START_X_POS + START_WIDTH) && ypos <= (START_X_POS + START_HEIGHT )) {
```

Comment: xpos < 400 && ypos < 190 DEPENDS ON image dimensions + start poistion. So if width is 20 and height is 30 make it xpos <= (160 + 20) && ypos < (160 + 30) ...

Comment: I guess I should have said the size of the image. It is 256x64 pixels.

Comment: you should add some loggers/ system out println to see state of your variables and debug